# The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly whit inner null reference exception

Tags: c#, build, nullreferenceexception, win-universal-app

I'm making a Windows universal application 10, but when I build my solution, I've this error whit an inner exception.

> The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> **`System.NullReferenceException`:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> ```
> at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResGenDependencies.TryGetPortableLibraryInfo(String libraryPath)
> at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.GetResourcesToProcess(List1& inputsToProcess, List1& outputsToProcess, List`1& cachedOutputFiles)
> at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
> ```

What does it mean? I've no information about whit file or line I had this.

I use Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using ? Update 1 or no ? Have you tried to clean the solution before building it ?

Comment: Are you refering to UWP or the (old) Windows 8.1 universal SDK ?

Comment: @Jmix90: the new UWP 10

Comment: @ThomasLEBRUN: VS Proffesional 2015 update 0. Yes, I have clean it, rebuild it restart VS etc...

Comment: Can you try to update Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx 

That solved the issue for me.